# Find a source and target branch name

Tags: linux, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

I have a stage in my ci-cd pipeline:

```
version_check:main:
  stage: main
  script:
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
    - echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
```

and the output in CI log is:

```
$ echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME=
$ echo CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME=$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME=
```

how can I get source and destination branch name in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

```
version_check:main:
  stage: main
  only:
    - merge_request
  script:
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
```

the output is:

```
$ echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}
ALXX3-2663
$ echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
master
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).